# настройка производительности yandex-tank\phantom

Tags: яндекс-танк

Существует задача - нагрузить вэб-сервер на канале в 10Гбит\сек. Как лучше сконфигурировать `yandex-tank\phantom` для максимальной производительности? Танк развернут на конфигурации 64 ядра AMD Opteron 6276 (4CPUx16) и 64 ГБ памяти DDR3. Нагрузка выводится в один порт Intel X520 (макс. 10 Гбит\сек)

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум стоит выкрутить лимит на число открытых файлов (ulimit -n) и увеличить диапазон доступных портов (net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range). Возможно имеет смысл поднять несколько адресов на сетевом интерфейсе, т.к при большом rps-е может начать не хватать портов.

В [документации](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#tuning) приведены дополнительные опции sysctl, но кажется что часть из них устарела. По крайней мере [тут](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html) написано что на клиенте (а у нас танк является клиентом) net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1 смысла не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо! Но, к сожалению, прирост в производительности минимален. Буду думать дальше =)

Comment: а что по загрузке ресурсов на танке и на мишени? Какой размер запросов и ответов? http или https?

Comment: На сервере танка каждый тред фантома грузит cpu на 90%. На мишени треды nginx'а грузят cpu на ~50%. Соединение настроено по SSLv2. Средний размер запроса ~70кБ.

Comment: А сколько у вас получилось запросов в секунду?

Comment: Ошибся. Размеры запросов\ответов следующие: `Avg Request size 38 bytes` и `Avg Response size 22211 bytes`. Фантом настроен на генерацию 50000 запросов в секунду.

Comment: @Direvius это же почти предел для phantom при стрельбах в https, как ты говорил?

Comment: можно наверное поэкспериментировать с набором cipher suits, чтобы облегчить дешифрование ответов.

Comment: Удалось достичь трафика в 2,3 Гбит\сек. на ответах с мишени. Заменил всю графику сайта на переименованные видео (грубо говоря, была картинка arrow-next.png размером в 23 байта. Переименовал файл видео video.avi размером в 78 МБ arrow-next.png). Так же, добавил в секцию `[phantom]` параметр `affinity=1-60`, т.е. привязал фантом к 60-ти физическим ядрам CPU.

Comment: По поводу `cipher suits` - я так понимаю, можно задать сразу несколько сертификатов, так? Но тогда нужно каким-то образом заставить `nginx` работать с этим же набором сертификатов для одного сайта...

Comment: И еще - не подскажите, где можно почитать информацию по настройке танка для стрельбы по нескольким мишеням?

Comment: cipher suit это не сертификат, а несколько алгоритмов + MAC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite), клиент (в данном случае фантом), при установлении коннекта сообщает что он поддерживает такие-то и такие-то cipher suits, сервер имея свой набор suits-ов, выбирает из этих двух множеств один, который поддерживается обоими сторонами. По дефолту танк шлет список всех suits-ов которые поддерживает openssl на машине где он установлен, поэтому достаточно настроить только nginx (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ciphers)

Comment: настройка стрельб в несколько мишеней - https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#multi-tests. Только учтите, что процесс фантома при этом будет все так же один

Comment: мы как раз сталкивались со стрельбами по SSL с одной машинки и с примерно такими же размерами ответов +) Да, там тоже получалось примерно 50К рпс с машинки. Чтобы догрузить сервак, ставили второй танк. У вас процессор полностью утилизируется фантомом? Если да, то вряд ли получится еще разогнать -- шифрование затратное. Если нет, то можно попробовать запустить четыре процесса фантома (вручную) и каждому назначить свой процессор (numactl), потому что у каждого процессора своя память (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Hwloc.png). Не знаю, поможет ли это

Comment: @Direvius В принципе, задал в блоке `[phantom]` в параметре `affinity` 16 ядер. На выходе мишени в ответах идут все те же 2,3 Гбит\сек. Треды фантома грузят cpu в среднем на 35-40%. Есть ли возможность задавать лимит используемой памяти для каждого процесса фантома? Сейчас во время работы фантом использует практически все 64 ГБ. И да, как правильно запустить несколько процессов?=) нужно же как-то указать каждому процессу свой конфиг...

Comment: @Александр можно ужаться по вот этим параметрам https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#phantom-http-module-tuning-options. Кстати, какие у вас времена ответов?

Comment: Потеряли в документации дефолтное значение для phantom_http_entity - 8Мб //дока обновится после пересборки.

Comment: @r2d2 Сделал следующее: ядра для фантома назначил с той ноды, где расположена сетевая карта и с соседней (итого - те же 16 ядер). Так же, задал фантому следующие параметры: `threads=21`, `phantom_http_entity = 80M`, `instances=600`, `rps_schedule=const(50000,30s)`. Потребление памяти упало до 12-13 ГБ, загрузка cpu держится на тех же ~40%. При этом траффик на ответах мишени увеличился до 4,5 Гбит\сек. Почитал немного про `Instances` и `rps_schedule`. Думаю, теперь нужно поэкспериментировать с этими параметрами.

Comment: @r2d2 Если это, о чем я подумал, тогда статистика следующая: `Avg Times (all / 50000 RPS / last):
Overall:    6461 /    6461 /  13916
Connect:    3344 /    3344 /   8910
Send:       0 /       0 /      0 
Latency:    1430 /    1430 /   3568
Receive:    1685 /    1685 /   1437`

Comment: Еще заметил один момент. Вырос процент `110 Connection timed out` в статистике:  `HTTP for 50000 RPS:  
964  91.46%: 200 OK | 
90   8.54%: 404 Not Found | 
NET for 50000 RPS:  
1054  33.61%: 0 Success | 
66.39%: 110 Connection timed out`

Comment: @r2d2 @Direvius Таки достиг необходимого объема трафика в 10Гбит\сек!:) Осталась одна проблема - как уменьшить процент `Connection timed out` в статистике `NET`? На данный момент он составляет ~45% от всего объема трафика. Уже выставил различные таймауты `time_periods` в блоке `[aggregator]` - это помогло, но незначительно

Comment: @Александр нужно глянуть в phantom.log, там подробней указывается, на каком этапе произошел таймаут. Возможно часть ошибок возникает при connect-е, когда ядро не получает ответы на syn-ы за нужное время (http://www.justsomestuff.co.uk/wiki/doku.php/linux/syn_tcp_timeout)

Comment: @r2d2 решил проблему заменой ресурсов сайта на стороне вэб-сервера. Теперь процент `connection timed out` не превышает 5-7%. Для моего случая это довольно приемлимо.

Comment: В общем плане, производительность очень сильно тормозила из-за записи логов. При больших значениях `rps` и `instances` логи пишутся колоссальных размеров (до 150ГБ) + логирование было включено с опцией `all`

Comment: Эх, надо было посоветовать сразу проверить значение writelog и включить мониторинг не только мишени, но и танка - на графиках дисковой активности было бы видно что просаживание коррелирует с записью на диск. Мы так привыкли это делать что даже не подумали что в этом может быть проблема :(

Comment: @r2d2 как вариант - в мануалах более подробно описать данный момент :)